# Redis настройка IP адресов для внешнего подключения

Tags: redis, config

Документация гласит:

```
By default, if no "bind" configuration directive is specified, Redis listens
for connections from all the network interfaces available on the server.
It is possible to listen to just one or multiple selected interfaces using
the "bind" configuration directive, followed by one or more IP addresses.

Examples:

bind 192.168.1.100 10.0.0.1
bind 127.0.0.1 ::1
```

Однако мне абсолютно ничего не ясно, что означает "bind 192.168.1.100 10.0.0.1" и "bind 127.0.0.1 ::1"

Почему в первом bind два IP, что это дает?

Зачем во втором примере `::1`, что это дает?

Допустим я добавил IP для внешних подключений следующим образом:

```
bind 94.103.**.***
```

Как установить пароль при подключении по этому IP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если не придерживаться строгой терминологии - Bind в конфиге - это директива, указывающая на каких адресах к серверу можно подключится. Если не указывать, то можно подключаться с любого интерфейса (т.е. если у вас, например, 3 сетевых платы то подключение будет работать через все три плюс localhost. Надеюсь что такое localhost вы в курсе).

Что касается ::1 это IPv6 адрес обозначающий localhost, считайте что это пока не актуально.

Резюмируя - bind это привязка к конкретному ip через который можно зайти. Естественно что это ip одного из ваших сетевых интерфейсов.

Что касается пароля - [вот](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-your-redis-installation-on-ubuntu-14-04#step-4-%E2%80%94-configuring-a-redis-password) прекрасное описание того как это сделать. Тут сложно что то добавить. Если есть сложности с английским, то по ключевым словам вы наверняка нагуглите нужную вам инфу.